# Export constant in Typescript and import it in another module

Tags: typescript

I'm starting to try some TypeScript features and I want to export two constants in one module and import them and use it in another module like this:

```
// module1.ts
export const CAMPUS = 'campus';
export const TOKIO = 'tokio';

// module2.ts
import * as ThemeNameEnum from './module1';

export type IState = ThemeNameEnum.CAMPUS | ThemeNameEnum.TOKIO;
```

The VSCode is not recognizing the exported members and the compiler is giving me this error:

```
ERROR in /Users/elias/Documents/agora-binaria/crm-front/src/app/redux/theme/theme-reducer.ts (4,36): Namespace '"/Users/elias/Documents/agora-binaria/crm-front/src/app/redux/theme/theme-name-enum"' has no exported member 'CAMPUS'.
ERROR in /Users/elias/Documents/agora-binaria/crm-front/src/app/redux/theme/theme-reducer.ts (4,59): Namespace '"/Users/elias/Documents/agora-binaria/crm-front/src/app/redux/theme/theme-name-enum"' has no exported member 'TOKIO'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
    "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "outDir": "../dist/client",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What compiler settings are you using? Do you have a `tsconfig.json` that you can show us?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the tsconfig.json file content @TomFenech

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whereas the error message is somewhat misleading, it makes some sense. By `export const A = 'foo';` you're exporting a *variable*, but `type C = A;` tries to treat `A` as a *type*. And there isn't one. The example can be condensed further:

```
const A = 'foo';
const B = 'bar';

type C = A | B;
```

That will fail with "cannot find A and B" message (similarly to your code), because `A` and `B` are *variables*, not *types*. To solve your problem you need to get type of `A` and `B`:

```
type C = typeof A | typeof B;
```

Comment: Yes... You are totally right! What I tried to do is like saying: `I want the type C to be 'foo' or 'bar'` but without using simply strings. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep, last code snippet in the answer does exactly that (assuming that you have `A: 'foo'` and `B: 'bar'`, e.g. as constant declared as in the first snippet). For your example you can write `type IState = typeof ThemeNameEnum.CAMPUS | typeof ThemeNameEnum.TOKIO;`.

Comment: Umm okay! I thought that `typeof ThemeNameEnum.CAMPUS` for example will return `string`. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It would be if, for example, we'd use `let` instead of `const` or explicitly typed it as `string` (i.e., `const A: string = 'foo'`). But since we left type of the constant for compiler to infer, it tries to come up with narrowest possible type (i.e., "precisest" one). Since a string declared as `const` can't be changed (the same way as e.g. a number), the narrowest type is the same string literal type as the value of the `const` variable.

Comment: And yes, note that `typeof` in type declarations is not the same `typeof` operator from JS.